# Best practice to test omniauth while running locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, local, omniauth

I am developing a Ruby on Rails app that should have social authorizations (the ability to log in via Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc., similar to StackOverflow).  For this, I am using the omniauth gem.

However, it looks like the web services (Facebook, Twitter, etc) will redirect to only one URL.

Is a best practice to set up two apps with the services, one for development, one for production?  The development one's redirect URL should be something like "localhost:3000/redirect/here" and the production one should be something like "mydomain.com/redirect/here"?

I am curious what other people have done for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either setup up different accounts and load the configuration based on the environment or create local aliases for your production domain so www.mydomain.com = localhost:3000